# Need to locate "hardware" text inside SPAN tag as part of Selenium practice from the below HTML

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, chropath

```
<li> 
<button> 
<span>software</span> 
<value>high risk</value> 
</button> <button> 
<span>hardware</span> 
<value>moderate risk</value> 
</button> <button> 
<span>software</span> 
<value>low risk</value> 
</button> 
<button> 
</li>
```

I have written

```
//*[contains(@value, 'moderate risk']//preceding::span
```

Tried with Chropath but it says "This element might be inside iframe from different src. Currently ChroPath doesn't support for them."

Since its a practice, I saved it as html file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is tag here not the `attribute`

Try below **xpath**.

```
//*[contains(text(), 'moderate risk')]//preceding-sibling::span
```

Comment: Isn't `/preceding-sibling::span` just enough ?

Comment: Working with both // and / before Preceding. one clarification on why "value" is tag and not attribute. you mean value tag is same as span tag here bcoz I see both the text on same button in html file. Am unfamiliar with value tag and so far used it as an attribute.

Comment: @JayB : Here `value` is a tag like `span` under parent `button`. The value  can be an attribute for element like `input` or `button` like if say html `<button value="moderate risk">moderate risk</button>` here value is an `attribute` But your case it is `tag`.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to locate with the below xpath as well which is similar to the one posted by @kunduk.

//*[contains(text(), 'moderate risk')]/preceding::span[1]